Why and how 先に is used in this sentence?

そんな噂を耳にしたら幻滅するとかそれよりも先にもしかしたら友達位にはなれるかもなんて思ってしまった

I understand the sentence is akin "After hearing the rumor, rather than being disillusioned,  I ended up thinking we could become friends"
But why is 先に used here?

Some context would help to determine whether それ refers to the time of 幻滅 or some other point of time. Either way, 先 means before that time, though.

He heard a bad news about this person, how he just goes along with everyone, etc but the narrator is happy because they want to be close to them
